# Clicking on an element in python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I'm trying to create a bot to add a 4k tv to my cart on BestBuy as a way to self teach myself selenium. I am having trouble with associating my 'element' variable to the button on BestBuy's website. I've been looking through some forums and cannot find a solution that works. I found the element through the HTML of the [BestBuy website](https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/samsung-75-4k-uhd-hdr-led-tizen-smart-tv-un75tu6900fxzc-2020-titan-grey-only-at-best-buy/14930256).

Here is an image of what I think is finding the element in chrome:
[image: chrome on BestBuy]

And here is my python code(excuse the sloppiness of my code I just started learning Selenium today):

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/samsung-75-4k-uhd-hdr-led-tizen-smart-tv-un75tu6900fxzc-2020-titan-grey-only-at-best-buy/14930256")
while True:
    if ("Add to Cart" in driver.page_source):
        print("In stock")
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("button_2Xgu4 primary_oeAKs.addToCartButton_1DQ8z.addToCartButton.regular_cDhX6")
        element.click()
        break
    else:
        print("Not in stock")
    driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/samsung-75-4k-uhd-hdr-led-tizen-smart-tv-un75tu6900fxzc-2020-titan-grey-only-at-best-buy/14930256");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `find_element_by_id`, and you put class name instead of the id of the element. However the element doesn't have any id, so you have to use `find_element_by_class_name` or `find_element_by_css_selector`.
I copied your code and I used class name. That didnt work, so I used css selector. And that worked.

Here you go:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='addToCartLabel_1eyxz']")
element.click()
```

You can learn more about finding elements [Here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html?highlight=find%20element#interacting-with-the-page).